# Diplaying a whole image in a label of defined size in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am fetching an image from the system and need to display it an new label when the button "Load image" is clicked. I need to display that complete image in a label named "canvas" of defined size but i am only getting a portion of the image.

my code is working just fine, its only that a portion of the image is being displayed.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk ,Image
import os

root = Tk()
root.title("Images")

def Clicked():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title="Select file", filetypes=(("png images", ".png, .jpg"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    if not filename:
        return
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filename))   #need to resize this image
    loaded = Label(frame, text = "\n\n\nLoaded Image\n", font = ('Arial',10,'bold')).grid(row = 5)
    canvas = Label(frame, width = 150, height =150, relief = "groove", borderwidth = 2, image = image)
    canvas.image = image
    canvas.grid(row = 6)


frame = Frame(root, relief = "solid", borderwidth = 1)
frame.pack()



label = Label(frame, text = "Content Based Image Retrieval\n", font = ('Arial', 15), padx = 10, pady =10).grid(row = 0)


content = Label(frame, text = "Contents\n\n",font=('Arial',10), padx = 20).grid(row = 1 , column = 0, sticky = W)

loadImg = Button(frame, text = "Load Image", relief = "groove", padx = 10, pady = 5, command = Clicked).grid( row = 2)

blank = Label(frame, text ="").grid(row = 3)

searchImg = Button(frame, text = "Search Image", relief = "groove", padx = 6, pady = 5).grid( row = 4)

blank = Label(frame, text ="").grid(row = 7)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to use some other library (for example, Pillow) to resize the image before displaying it. The only ability tkinter has to resize images is to rescale it in factors of two.